# How to set Analytics Tracking Event as download using Sitecore Powershell script

Tags: sxa, powershell-extensions, powershell

I'm trying to set Analytics Tracking Event as Download using Sitecore PowerShell script for most media items which have pdf extension.

like this:

[image]

**Below is the script, I have written but not working**

```
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path "master:/sitecore/media library/Files/Documentation Center/Reports/Reporting Brochure" -Recurse

foreach($item in $items){
 $fieldValue = $item."Extension"
if(-Not([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($fieldValue)) -and $item."Extension" -eq "pdf" )
{

    $item.Editing.BeginEdit();
    $item.Fields["__Tracking"].Value = "<tracking><event id='{FA72E131-3CFD-481C-8E15-04496E9586DC}' name='Download' /></tracking>"
    $item.Editing.EndEdit();
 
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried your script directly under the files folder with pdf files and it worked for me.

[image]

[image]

Few thinks you can try out.

1. Validate the extention of the file.
2. Put pdf file directly under file folder for testing and see if it works.

You can check the extension of the files you are trying for. Your screenshot does not show like pdf file. Validate the information section of the file.

[image]

```
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path "master:/sitecore/media library/Files" -Recurse

foreach($item in $items){
 $fieldValue = $item."Extension"
if(-Not([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($fieldValue)) -and $item."Extension" -eq "pdf" )
{

    $item.Editing.BeginEdit();
    $item.Fields["__Tracking"].Value = "<tracking><event id='{FA72E131-3CFD-481C-8E15-04496E9586DC}' name='Download' /></tracking>"
    $item.Editing.EndEdit();
 
}
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, Raman now the script is running my end also

Comment: I'm glad it helps you. If any of the answer works for you than you can mark it as accepted. Refer https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the script you have written is working and I am also able to set the tracking value.

[image]

You should debug your script to check the following.

1. Are you able to get the records in the variable `$items`
2. Use to write something in the console like below to see if your condition is getting fulfilled like below.

And check what items do not fulfill this condition by getting their ID in the console in the else part.

```
if(-Not([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($fieldValue)) -and $item."Extension" -eq "pdf" )
{
    Write-Host 'Item Found'
    $item.Editing.BeginEdit();
    $item.Fields["__Tracking"].Value = "<tracking><event id='{FA72E131-3CFD-481C-8E15-04496E9586DC}' name='Download' /></tracking>"
    $item.Editing.EndEdit();
 
}
else
{
    Write-Host 'Not Found'
    Write-Host $item.Id
}
```

Because the script you are using only does a normal Item edit operation and it may fail in the conditions you have written before doing this event.

3. Also, check if you manually update the value of Tracking field in one of the PDF items in your folder by viewing the raw values of the item and updating and saving it.

Hope this will give you an idea of what items it is failing.